# What is this variable be ([{ name, objectItem }, ...object]: any, row = [])

Tags: javascript, typescript

per title, what this variable be?

```
([{ name, objectItem }, ...object]: any, row = [])
object = {name, objectItem,nameError,nameHint,itemError,itemHint}
```

I know what `...` is, does this code only include as the first object suggested? so it only include `name`, and `objectItem` from the rest of the `object`

**EDIT**:

Move the answer to reply section

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].  As it stands your code [is full of errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/BQbQ3gBAdghgtgUwDQQPYCMBWCDGAXASTwTggF8UA6ajbfAXQC4IYoBPFAJ1QHcIBeCCHoBKAFC1ceARDCxEKSfiIkk8hAFFO3TmvgIAEgEsoeJEeJwtO85eOmyQA), so it's hard to say what is supposed to be happening in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever arrived into this question, this is [Destructuring assignment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function foo ([{ name, objectItem}, ...restObject]: any, row = []) {
/** Do something with variable name, objectItem, and object */
}
```

Function `foo` accept an array of object as parameters. This array of object consist property of `name`, `objectItem`, thus making it available as variable inside the function. While the rest of property goes to variable `restObject`.